# php : test for lines of array the condition range of date is between range of date

Tags: php, arrays, date, if-statement

I have a logic problem on how to filter entries within a range of date.

An array `$price` contains prices for a flight depending of the period of travel, ordered by date:

```
   print_r($price)
   [21] => Array            
        [date_beg] => 2014-07-05            
        [total1] => 648

   [22] => Array
        [date_beg] => 2014-08-05            
        [total1] => 750
   [23] => Array
        [date_beg] => 2014-08-12            
        [total1] => 520
```

It is 648 euros from 2014-08-05, then it becomes 750 from 2014-08-05  ...

I also have special offers at some periods.

The same information is present for each element of the array:

```
 print_r($price)
   [21] => Array            
        [date_beg] => 2014-07-05            
        [total1] => 648

        [special_beg] => 2014-07-07
        [special_end] => 2014-08-06
        [special_price] => 600

   [22] => Array
        [date_beg] => 2014-08-05            
        [total1] => 750

        [special_beg] => 2013-10-27
        [special_end] => 2013-12-18
        [special_price] => 600

   [23] => Array
        [date_beg] => 2014-08-12            
        [total1] => 520

        [special_beg] => 2013-10-27
        [special_end] => 2013-12-18
        [special_price] => 600
```

What I would like to do is feeding a new "display" array containing details of the special price for each element of the array that the promotion is valid for.

Something like:

```
          $nb_date=0;
          foreach($price as $a_price){
                if (($a_price['special_beg']>$a_price['date_beg']))
        //+ some other conditions
        {

                  $display[$nb_date]'special_beg']=$a_price['special_beg'];
                  $display[$nb_date]'special_end']=$a_price['special_end'];
                  $display[$nb_date]'special_price']=$a_price['special_price'];
                  $display[$nb_date]'promo_web']=$a_price['promo_web'];
                  $display[$nb_date]['promo_text']=$a_price['promo_text'];
                  ...etc...
                }
           $nb_date++;
          }
```

I have tried quite a few things with no success.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to convert a date string to a date object. Otherwise your `>` operator is working on two strings and strings get compared differently than dates do. There may be a better way...

```
$nb_date=0;

//Make sure to set Default Timezone when working with DateTime class
//Set This from the list: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 

//DateTime object with current Date/Time 
$now = new DateTime(); 

foreach($price as $a_price){

    //I *think* this is the logic you want, making sure the current
    //date is after the beginning date.

    $date_beg = new DateTime($a_price['date_beg']);
    if ( $now > date_beg ){ 

       $display[$nb_date]['special_beg']=$a_price['special_beg'];
       ...

    }
    $nb_date++;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it won't filter out the lines where the special_end is > date_end

Comment: You need to add that condition to the `if` statement. I don't know what specific conditions you are looking for. Your code showed `+ some other conditions` - that's what should go there. Use the code I provided to create DateTime objects for the dates you're talking about and put them into the `if` statement. I'm trying to help you write your code, while not writing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

i have finally managed to do it like this :

-convert date to Datetime object
 -create 2 conditions while parsing the array and a switch to say we are now entering promotional dates...something like that:

```
    $promo_has_started='false';

            foreach ( $grille_tarifs as $key => $value)
            {

             $date_promo_resa_debut = new DateTime($grille_tarifs[$key]['date_promo_resa_debut']);
             $date_promo_resa_fin = new DateTime($grille_tarifs[$key]['date_promo_resa_fin']);
             $date = new DateTime($grille_tarifs[$key]['date']);
             $date_fin= new DateTime($grille_tarifs[$key]['date_fin']);


                if (($grille_tarifs[$key]['promo_heberg']==$_POST['vt_heberg'])||($grille_tarifs[$key]['promo_heberg']==$_POST['vt_croisi'])||(!(isset($_POST['vt_heberg'])))&& (!(isset($_POST['vt_croisi']))))


                    if (($date_promo_resa_debut<$date_fin)&&($promo_has_started=='false' ))
                    {
                        $promo_has_started='true';
                        $grille_tarifs[$key]['promo_web']='display';

                    }
                    else if (($promo_has_started=='true')&&($date_promo_resa_fin >=$date))
                    {
                        $promo_has_started='true';
                        $grille_tarifs[$key]['promo_web']='display';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $grille_tarifs[$key]['promo_web']='oui';
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Great! You should probably delete this answer, and append the content of it to your original question.